# How can I tell difference between app in background and app closed with Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I am trying to find a way to tell if an application has been closed or has went to the background. I need the ability to do this with any application. I am using the AcitivityManager to poll which applications are running, and compare them to an application I am looking for. The problem is that the importance level gets set to IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND when it is actually in the background AND when I use the back button to "close" the app. How can I tell if it is actually closed or in the background?

```
private boolean isActivityRunning(){
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
        Log.d(TAG, "Polling Serivce at application " +procInfos.get(i).processName);
        if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals(appLaunchedPackage)&&
            (procInfos.get(i).importance ==RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE || 
                    procInfos.get(i).importance ==RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND || 
                    procInfos.get(i).importance ==RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND)  ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Polling Serivce - the app has been found!");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: couldn't you override onPause() or onStop() in the activity and set a flag indicating it is in the background?

Comment: I don't have access to the code of other apps, that's where my problem is. I need a way to tell if other apps are closed.

Answer (score 1):

App in android in not "closed" when you hit back button. Back button invokes previous Activity on activity stack and puts current one in the background.

So home button clears the activity stack and invokes launcher app, back button invokes previous activity from stack. Both put current app in background.

Apps on android are only closed, i.e. killed and removed from memory, when system is low on resources.

Comment: Yea I definitely understand that hence the quotes around close ;) I was just hoping there is some way to tell the difference. I know there is something, for example. The task manager in the Samsung version of Android can tell the difference, though I'm not sure if I have access to that.

Comment: What did you mean by "task manager on Samsung can tell the difference"? I have a Samsung, where do I see that?

Comment: The easiest way to see is to use it as a widget. It is actually called Program Monitor. It's actually pretty nice and has been helpful for my problem.

Comment: @Peter I don't get your first sentence. Then why does onDestroy() get called on back button (immediately after opening app, for example)?

Comment: If you call `finish()` on it or if OS decidees it does not need it anymore.

Comment: ah so the back button really just calls finish(), in my case.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the back button to switch back from your app to the desktop, the application goes background. It is not closed.

Android will close it later, if needed, and this will not be the result of a user action.